# Is it possible to set the order or priority of applications by package name when creating a deep link?

Tags: android, deep-linking

In Android, I have encountered an issue where several applications are configured to handle identical scheme-host URI combinations. While creating a deep link is feasible, the processing of such links by the Android system is not as expected. The system does not prompt users to choose an application to open the link. Furthermore, it does not default to the app most frequently used by the user.

Is there a way to embed a specific package name within a deep link? This would be beneficial as the applications in question are not under my control, hence I am unable to modify the host. Additionally, directly launching an intent is not within my purview. My role is limited to generating a deep link and distributing it through a messaging service.